# Please allow close voting when viewing a suggested duplicate in the Close votes Review Queue

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I would love to see an improved workflow for when I review a duplicate question.
My current workflow looks like this:

1. Read the question that is nominated for closure
2. Read the suggested duplicate target(s)
3. Return back to the question
4. Take an action on the post

Especially here on MSE we get a lot of duplicate questions, and as a somewhat regular user I usually know a question is a duplicate after I read the first few sentences of a post in the queue. More often then not I also know the appropriate duplicate target. So when I switch to the duplicate tab I almost instantaneously know if it is the right duplicate target or not. I would love to then just be done with it by casting the close vote.

However the review queue currently forces me to move back to the original post's tab, to be able to complete my review.

This [used to be allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352961/377214), but it became broken following some changes to the old review queue layout, and was fixed by removing the option in the new layout.

#### Can we please be a bit more mindful of reviewers and display the action box on all tabs?

Comment: Technically it's a dupe of this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352961/282094 ***because*** they say they'll reply there when the new queues are out ***and*** it's fixed - **but** in this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360519/282094 to the "New Reviews Queues Announcement" they say that this breakage is now status-by-design (*that's* how they fixed it); so perhaps you prefer that your question is a duplicate of that answer (Feedback, on the Announcement) - clarifying that it's a Feature Request for a recently denied bug report.

Comment: @Rob It's perfectly fine to file a feature request to change the design in response to a bug report that gets dismissed as by design. Such questions shouldn't be closed as duplicates.

Comment: Don't know if it justifies a separate request or could be "merged" into this one, but personally I would like to see the same for other queues. For example, reviewing a Late Answer, going to the "other answers" tab to see if it's a repeated answer, going back to answer and acting (either looks ok, skip or whatever). Here as well, it would be nice to have the actions box on the other answers tab as well